# Parse GeoPoints React Native

Tags: parse-platform, geolocation, react-native, geopoints

I have [image: Parse Data]

How I can get users near user with username 2?

In Parse instruction:

```
var userGeoPoint = userObject.get("location");
var query = new Parse.Query(PlaceObject);
query.near("location", userGeoPoint);
query.limit(10);
query.find({
  success: function(placesObjects) {   }
```

There is a code for a usual query:

```
var Tweet = Parse.Object.extend("Recommend");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Tweet);
    query.equalTo("username", "2");
    query.find({
      success: (tweets) => this.setState({tweets}),
      error: (error) => console.error(error),
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (

      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.tweets.map(
          tweet => <Cellrec tweet={tweet} />
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
});
```

It works well.
I don't know how to make it with geopoint.

I try:

```
  var Tweet = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var userGeoPoint = userObject.get("Location");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Tweet);
  query.near("Location", userGeoPoint);
  query.equalTo("username", "2");
  query.find({
    success: (tweets) => this.setState({tweets}),
    error: (error) => console.error(error),
  });
},
   render: function() {
     return (

       <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
         {this.state.tweets.map(
           tweet => <Cellrec tweet={tweet} />
         )}
       </ScrollView>
     );
   }
 });
```

But it does not work.Error
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.tweets.map')

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Question-  which code for this case?  
How I can get users near user with username 2?